# Find the command pycharm is launching when running the program

Tags: pycharm

In pycharm we click the "Run" button to run the python file. Is it possible to see what command pycharm is launching to run the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command will be shown at the top of `Run` tool window, see second screenshot here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/code-running-assistance-tutorial.html#straight_forward_way